# This name is ambiguous due to multiple matches:

Tags: alloy

I have an Alloy model, that have 2 signatures which have a relation that have the same name.

```
sig Model { 
    components : set Component
}

sig Port extends Element {
    belongsTo : Component
}

sig Component extends Element{
    belongsTo : Model,
    ports : set Port
}
```

When I try to access these relation threw join the solver throws me:

```
A type error has occured:
This name is ambiguous due to multiple matches:
field this/Port <: belongsTo
field this/Component <: belongsTo
```

Is there any way to specify explicitly that I want to access to the relation `belongTo` of component and not the port one, when I do:

```
all m : m.belongsTo |
```

and m are models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say

```
all x: m.(Component <: belongsTo) | ...
```